# Binding to 0.0.0.0 only picked up local addresses

Tags: networking, ssh, arch-linux

I'm not a server guy, and my network skills are a little rusty, so this may be a simple question. On a brand-new archlinux machine, I setup sshd, and told it to bind to 0.0.0.0:9223. Once it was running, I used netstat to confirm that it was listening on *:9223.

Running "ssh -p 9223 localhost" connected fine, but remote connections failed. I then tried "ssh -p 9223 [REMOTE_IP]" on the server, and this failed.

After trying to find the source of the problem, and failing, I set sshd to bind to [REMOTE_IP], and suddenly everything worked.

So my question is, what would cause a socket bound to 0.0.0.0 to ignore connections from the ip address of the eth0 interface?

Comment: What was the error message when you tried "ssh -p 9223 remote_ip"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The case might be that your eth0 interface is using IPv6 protocol. When you configure ssh server with `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you turned off IPv6 protocol. `netstat` then have only one entry for ssh starting with `tcp`. Add a line `ListenAddress ::` to also listen on `tcp6`. `netstat` should report you two entries for ssh server one on `tcp6 :::9223` and one on `tcp 0.0.0.0:9223`

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: How is IPv6 related? O_o